# Cannot search/ filter table if the row data has '&' in the text

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a html table with 7 columns and 6000+ rows.

I searched the web for the JavaScript code and tweaked a bit to perform the search and filter function for my html table and it's working fine!

The only problem is with character '&'. Wherever this '&' exist in the data it doesn't search after '&'.

For example the sample data has 'Koniglich & Essen' in customer name column. So when I start typing, it will show result till I type 'Koniglich &'. After i type ' E....' the result disappears.

Below is the sample page.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G99OS1TL3YD0

Below is the JavaScript code I am using to filter data.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i,
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will work (using `.textContent`): https://jsfiddle.net/jvd4wfoh/

Comment: Hello @hev1 please post this as an answer. Your linked helped me to fix this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `textContent` of each table cell instead of the `innerHTML` which escapes special characters into HTML entities; `&` would be changed to `&amp;`

Change:

```
if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
```

To

```
if (td.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jvd4wfoh/

Answer (score 0):

You're examining `innerHTML` so the `&` will be represented as `&amp;` when the browser converts it to HTML.

A `console.log(td.innerHTML)` would have highlighted this.

You would probably be better off examining `textContent`.

Comment: I do not have knowledge about javascript at all. This is the first time i am dealing with it so I don't know how and where to implement `textContent`. I did try the `textValue` as shown in This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) however, this wasn't filtering anything! Not even a single row. The code was unresponsive. Could you please modify my code with `textContent` and show me?